Reference for the "essay" as a preliminary drawing or sketch in the visual arts
In literature, an essay is a name given to a piece of writing in which the author presents their arguments and experiences with regards to a certain topic.
According to this page on the visual arts, the name "essay" is also designated to a preliminary drawing or sketch that forms a basis for a final painting or sculpture.
Although I imagine this may very well be the case, it appears this assertion is not backed up by a reference. I have tried finding such a reference by searching with relevant terms on Google Scholar, but haven't been able to find such a reference over there either.
I therefore wonder whether there are any research papers or other sources where the essay in the visual arts is defined as such.
Question

Are there any references (academic papers or otherwise) in which the essay is defined as "a preliminary drawing or or sketch forms a basis for a final painting or sculpture" in the context of the visual arts?


I may have heard essay used that way back in art school in an 17 or 18 century  treatise on a sculpture. Certainly not in common use. May have better luck in https://english.stackexchange.com/

I thought maybe it was a language thing as essay derives from Old French for 'to try' but it looks like French for a study done for a painting or sculpture is equisse.
